# chose also between windows installations (win10/win11/ubuntu) with grub customizer instead windows boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm using grub customizer in Ubuntu 20.04 to dualboot into ubuntu/windows, but I also have two windows versions installed in following setup:

1tb M.2:

- Windows 10 pro (Main)

250gb M.2:

- Partition 1: Windows 11 pro (for testing)
- Partition 2: Ubuntu 20.04 (for other stuff)

now it would be great if I could chose the windows version directly in the grub boot menu instead later in windows boot manager (wen I start my pc it first shows the grub boot menu and if I chose windows it shows me the windows boot manager wehre I have to chose between the two windows installations)

is it even possible to do it like that?
(sorry if I ask in the wrong forum)

my pc hardware:

- CPU: i7 10700k
- GPU: RTX 2070s
- MainBoard: Asus ROG Strix Z490-F Gaming
- 16gb DDR4 Ram

here a picture on how it should look like
https://i.ibb.co/7SfTc28/C2-CAC134-710-B-4-F5-E-9112-30-F44-B6-A06-C1.png